# Is a ring homomorphism into a center always injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$and $A$ be rings with $A \neq \{0\}$. Furthermore, assume that $R$ is unitary and commutative. Let $\eta: R \to Z(A)$ be a ring homomorphism where $Z(A)$ denotes the center of $A$.

> > **Question**: Is $\eta$ always injective?

**Approach**

I think the statement is true, and I tried the following: Let $r \in R$ such that $\eta(r)=0_A$. Assume that $r \neq 0_R$. If $R$ would be a field or, more generally, if $r$ has an inverse in $R$, we get $$1_A = \eta(r) \eta(r^{-1}) = 0_A$$ which would be a contradiction since we assumed $A \neq \{ 0\}$. But I cannot complete the proof for the case when $R$ is not a field.

Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What is the point of talking about the center of a commutative ring?

Comment: Try $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb F_p$.

Comment: What about $\eta: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z_4} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ via $x \mapsto x\pmod{2}$.

Comment: If $A$ is assumed commutative, then $Z(A)=A$. So your question becomes “is every ring homomorphism between commutative rings with identity injective?” in which case, the answer becomes obvious. And even if you drop the assumption that $A$ is commutative, it *still* reduces to exactly the same thing...

Comment: @rschwieb: Regarding your first comment: You are right, my bad! I changed the question and hope it makes more sense now. I tried to generalize https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Algebras_and_rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t finish it because it’s false. Let $R$ be a unitary commutative ring that is not a field. Then $R$ has a nontrivial proper ideal $I$ (a unitary commutative ring with no nontrivial proper ideals is a field). Take $A=R/I$ and $\eta$ the canonical projection. Note that $Z(A)=A$.

If you want your $A$ to be *strictly* non-commutative (as opposed to “not necessarily commutative”, then note that if $S$ is any commutative unitary ring, then you can let $A=S\langle x,y\rangle$ be the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $S$ on the noncommuting variables $x$ and $y$. The center of this ring is the copy of $S$ inside it, and you can take any non-injective map $R\to S$ and compose it with the embedding $S\hookrightarrow A$ to get a non-injective map $R\to A$.

Comment: Thank you! Last (trivial) question: My guess that the statement is true if $R$ is a field, right?

Comment: @Diglett: If your rings-with-unity morphisms require the unity to be mapped to the unity, and $S$ is nontrivlal, yes. In general, a ring homomorphism from a field is either zero or injective.